# Can't break any block in survival in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing survival. At first I could break blocks and do all sorts of things but now I can't. First of all I am not playing in adventure mode or anything. I believe it is a glitch of some sort. This problem initiated when minecraft crashed. Please HELP!

Comment: sometimes when I want to open my world it returns the main menu.

Comment: Nope not at all. I told first that it is in survival not adventure.  Besides my cheats are off

Comment: What if you start a new world?

Comment: What where you doing before that (installed a mod maybe?). More context is needed...

Answer (score 0):

Create a new world and see if that fixes it, if not simply "force update" Minecraft by going to options on the launcher. This will install a clean copy of Minecraft. You may also want to check that your controlls are all in order.

This happened to me and my controls were all weird (like space to hit). This also happened after a crash.

Comment: It is like that in only that world

Comment: I think your world may be bugged or something :/ Is this your main world?

Comment: I went in to the Roaming file (AppData) and have seen that the world itself is missing. However it displays on the minecraft worlds area. Now even if I click it it returns the title screen. Is there a way to recover the world

Comment: I don't believe there is :/ I feel sorry if this was like your main survival world haha.

Comment: What did the crash report say? Like what was happening before the crash happened?